# Solving equation $2t=-\tan(1/t)$

Tags: calculus, parametric

I am trying to solve the equation $2t = -\tan(1/t)$, where $t \in (0,1)$. Is there going to be an infinite or finite number of answers?

Comment: Since $t \in(0,1)$, then if there is a solution, for sure it is a finite number.

Comment: @the_candyman - why?

Comment: @the_candyman How can you be sure? $-\tan(1/t)$ oscillates faster and faster.

Comment: J.ba said that $t \in (0,1)$, right? Then, if there is a solution, it is inside $(0,1)$ and any number inside $(0,1)$ are finite, right?

Comment: @the_candyman - he asked about "finite number of answers", not whether the answers themselves will be finite numbers.

Comment: @mathguy sorry, I misread the final part of the question.

Comment: @Jba - what do you mean by "solve" the equation? You will not be able to find the solutions in closed form. Do you just want to know if there is a finite number of solutions? The answer is no. Please clarify what you are really trying to do.

Comment: @mathguy Yeah I mean whether there is a finite number of solutions. Could you prove why the solutions is infinite?

Answer (score 3):

As you can see, good luck :-D $\ $ [image]

Answer (score 2):

Letting
$y = 1/t$,
$2t = -\tan(1/t)
$ becomes
$-2 = y \tan(y)$
with
$y > 1$.

Since
$\tan(k\pi) = 0$,
let's look at
$z_k =(k\pi-c)\tan(k\pi-c_k)$
where $c_k$ is small.

$\begin{array}\\
z_k
&=(k\pi-c_k)\tan(k\pi-c_k)\\
&=(k\pi-c_k)\tan(-c_k)\\
&=-(k\pi-c_k)\tan(c_k)\\
&=-(k\pi-c_k)(c_k+O(c_k^3))\\
&=-k\pi c_k+c^2+O(kc_k^3))\\
\end{array}
$

So if
$c_k 
\approx \frac{2}{k\pi}
$,
then
$z_k
\approx -2
$.

By continuity
and a little fudging,
there is a
$d_k \approx c_k$
such that
$(k\pi-d_k)\tan(k\pi-d_k)
= -2
$
so that
$\dfrac{2}{k\pi-d_k}
=-\tan\left(\dfrac1{k\pi-d_k}\right)
$.

So there are an infinite
number of solutions,
which cluster around zero.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=1/t$.  The equation $\tan(x)=-2/x$ obviously has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: I hate the word "obviously". Instead of saying it's obvious, just say why it is in like 3 more words. It follows from considering the graphs of $\tan x$ and $-2/x$.

Comment: A reluctant +1 anyway, though, for the substitution.

Comment: More generally, $\tan x = f(x)$ has infinitely many solutions for any $f$ which is defined and continuous at all but finitely many points in $\mathbb{R}$.